# How to show json data in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is static html code

```
<div class="EquipmentContent row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 subSection" style="float:right;background:#dff0ff;">  
        <section class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 cl-md-2 col-lg-2">
          <label class="equipmentHeaderlable">Name</label>
          <label class="equipmentHeaderValues">SSS</label>
        </section>
        <section class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1 cl-md-1 col-lg-1">
          <button type="button" style="display: inline-block;float:right;" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="hideEquipmentDetails()"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
        </section>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I am trying to change it as dynamic.Which means I need to show json data in this div.So I tried like this

```
var content= response.data.filters;
$.each(content,function(i,value){                       
    $('.subSection').html("<section class='col-xs-12 col-sm-2 cl-md-2 col-lg-2'><label class='equipmentHeaderlable'>Name</label><label class='equipmentHeaderValues'>"+value.name+"</label></section>").appendTo('.EquipmentContent');

})
```

But am getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list` error.What I did wrong?

Comment: According to this https://api.jquery.com/each/ the only parameter for `each` is a function. Your code above has 2. Can it be that? What is the possible value of the `content` variable? You could try doing it like $(content).each(function(i, value) {});

Comment: @CodeLover, He is using this alternative http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/, so his code is correct

Comment: Oh. I see. But this is weird. I do not see a missing `)` here.

Comment: :-(:-( whats wrong with my code??

Comment: There is no missing bracket in the code you've posted. Please show a [mcve] demonstrating the problem to get an answer.

Comment: have you used code tag

Comment: @skhurams code tag??..

Comment: guys Is there any other way to show json data in a div using jquery?

Comment: guys please check my answer below and let me know the corrections.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Guys am getting data dynamically by changing all single `'` to `"` and all `"` to `'` and Dont use `.html()` it will append only current value.so try to use `.append()`

```
$('.subSection').append('<section class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 cl-md-2 col-lg-2"><label class="equipmentHeaderlable">Name</label><label class="equipmentHeaderValues">'+value.name+'</label></section>');
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. You should have updated your question not posted an answer.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can write it a bit cleaner and know that you are missing something.But i guess you are not. maybe you are missing some other bracket in the code above. I suggest you comment this part and see if the error still occurs.

```
var content= response.data.filters;
$.each(content,function(i,value){   
      var data = "<section class='col-xs-12 col-sm-2 cl-md-2 col-lg-2'>";
      data += "<label class='equipmentHeaderlable'>Name</label>";
      data += "<label class='equipmentHeaderValues'>"+value.name+"</label></section>";    
      $('.subSection').html(data).appendTo('.EquipmentContent');

});
```

Comment: yes If I comment it means other part of code is working fine.

Comment: can you view the page source and see what exists in content variable?

Comment: Youve introduced bugs (using `'` instead of `"` for strings)